# crystal report arabic fonts with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I create website displays  Crystal Reports build with asp.net v4

When running the Report Display works and appears correctly but when you print or export to pdf file

Shows the formation of the Arabic words and the words stick together there is a single font without this problem is @ Arial Unicode MS

But inappropriate Is there another Font or other things to resolve this problem thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your data fields in crystal reports, right click the field and select format object.
Format your text to be displayed by selecting options like Can Grow, Keep text together.

Comment: can you post a look n feel of your crystal report. An image will work.